# In how many ways can a board of five people that includes the male Head of School be formed if it must include at least two men and two women?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

An appointments board must consist of the Head of School and exactly 4 other
members of the School chosen from a group consisting of 3 men and 4 women. If
the overall board of 5 people must include at least 2 women and at least 2 men and
the Head of School is male, how many different makeups are possible?

I have attempted this question and I got 2 different makeups is possible- two men (including Head of School) & three women and three men (including Head of School) & two women? Could someone tell me if I'm correct or if I'm taking too simple an approach to this question?

Comment: People are distinguishable.

Comment: But they have the same positions available to them so does it matter that they're distinguishable?

Comment: The groups that include Bob have different make-ups from those that do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have attempted this question and I got 2 different makeups is possible- two men (including Head of School) & three women and three men (including Head of School) & two women? Could someone tell me if I'm correct or if I'm taking too simple an approach to this question?

You are correct *so far*.   However, remember that people are distinguishable objects.   Now count how many distinct ways there are to select those combinations from the head of school, 3 other men, and 4 women.